# Listar ficheros de una carpeta web

Tags: php

Estoy intentando listar ficheros de una carpeta web con PHP.
Tengo un codigo que des de la misma carpeta, funciona bien.
Pero el problema es que quiero ejecutarlo des de otro sitio.
En mi pagina web, quiero listar los ficheros de otro web, para entendernos.

De antemano decir que tengo muyyy pocos conocimientos de programación.

Si esto es posible i alguien pude ayudarme, perfecto :)

Saludos

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Aunque tengas pocos conocimientos de programación, ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro].

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: *En mi pagina web, quiero listar los ficheros de otro web, para entendernos. ... Si esto es posible ...* La respuesta es **NO**, no podrás invadir desde tu servidor otro servidor para leer sus ficheros, a no ser que ese servidor te dé la forma de hacerlo, por ejemplo mediante una API. Y si el servidor permite ese acceso directamente desde otra web como pretendes, tendría las horas contadas.

Comment: Hola de nuevo
Esta claro que he cometido algunos errores de principiante. Lo siento.
El ejemplo no lo puse porque tenia que editar partes del codigo para eliminar las URL internas... 
De hecho, el codigo que tengo, supongo es muy simple. Ejecuto un PHP en la misma carpeta que tengo PDF's y me muestra un listado de estos ficheros. 

La duda, que creo me ha respondido  @A. Cedano,  es que no podre leer ficheros de un dominio des de otro dominio, y esta es mi intencion...

Si os parece que es posible, facilmente... puedo hacer pruebas. 

gracias

Comment: no importa que tan simple sea el codigo... si no muestras que has intentando la pregunta sera cerrada ya que en el sitio no se hace codigo desde 0, si no que si tienes algun error en el codigo podemos ayudarte a solucionarlo... por ende necesitamos el codigo, el error y que esperas que suceda realmente.

Comment: *... si es posible ... leer ficheros de un dominio desde otro dominio* Posible es, pero del modo ya dicho: exponiendo esos ficheros en un entorno seguro, por ejemplo una API. Así puedes consultar los ficheros pasando por dicha API. Todo esto es por cuestiones de seguridad. Si es para algo personal, y los dos dominios están en el mismo hosting compartido, lo puedes hacer internamente, pero esto tiene un uso limitado, nada más de un dominio A a un dominio B.